# Don't understand multiple parameter declarations in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

can someone clarify this for me:

When there’s more than one argument, the arguments are declared within the method name after the colons.
Arguments break the name apart in the declaration, just as in a message. For example:

```
- (void)setWidth:(float)width height:(float)height;
```

So in the above:

1. method is for instance variables
2. returns void
3. parameter#1 is a float, named width.
4. parameter#2 is a float,named height.

But why is it hieght:(float)height; and not just:

```
- (void)setWidth: (float)width (float)height;
```

Answer (score 8):

Objective-C **does not have named arguments**.  Nor does it have "keyword arguments".

Objective-C uses what is called "interleaved arguments". That is, the name of the method is interleaved with the arguments so as to produce more descriptive and readable code.

```
[myObject setWidth:w height:h];
```

The above reads, effectively, as *tell myObject to set the width to w and height to h*.

In the above case, the method's name -- its **selector** -- is exactly `setWidth:height:`.  No more, no less.

This is all explained in the [Objective-C guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf).

Comment: "so as to produce more descriptive and readable code". It turns out they achieved the exact opposite.

Answer (score 2):

That's just a feature of Objective-C to make your life easier when reading the method invocation, which would look like:

```
[myObject setWidth:w height:h];
```

You can leave the labels out (except the first one), so if you *really* want to, you can have:

```
-(void)setWidth:(float)width :(float)height
{
  ...
}
```

and use it as:

```
[myObject setWidth:w :h];
```

But that's not really in the spirit of the Objective-C language.  The entire point of those labels is to make those calls easier to understand without having to look up the method definition.

Comment: Objective-C does *not* have "labeled" arguments.  You can't just leave out part of a method name.  That is, in the above example the method 'setWidth::' is a different method from 'setWidth:height:' (this often confuses new folk).

Comment: @bbum, yes absolutely.  I didn't mean to create any impression that they are the same.  Do you have a suggestion for how I can clarify that?

Comment: I haven't come up with a terribly good description beyond "Objective-C interleaves the method names with the arguments to improve readability and descriptiveness within code.".

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the argument name happens to also be in the method name is confusing you. Think about how you actually call it:

```
[something setWidth:500 height:250];
```

Following your suggestion, it would be something like this instead:

```
[something setWidth:500 250]; // That 250 is just kind of hanging 
                              // out there — not very readable
```

You could also give the argument a totally different name from the part of the method name that precedes it:

```
- (void)setGivenName:(NSString *)first surname:(NSString *)last
```

Comment: just confusing, in c# it would be:
void SetWidth(int width, int height);
object.SetWidth(500, 200);

there seems to be something a bit strange, all parameters don't seem to be the same convention.

Comment: actually in C# it would be void SetDimensions(int width, int height); object.SetDimensions(500, 200);