# Understanding named vs positional function call in Swift

Tags: swift, function, arguments

I'm encountering an issue with my code and I'm trying to understand why the initial call to `add` fails with a "Missing argument" error, while it runs successfully when passed to a different function where it is called without the argument labels.

I found a discussion on this topic at [Why does Swift require parameter names if it also requires argument order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58346262/why-does-swift-require-parameter-names-if-it-also-requires-argument-order), but I'm having trouble grasping all the details and determining its relevance to my query.

```swift
func add(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {
    x + y
}

func wrapper(function: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int {
    function(1, 2)  // Why does this not produce a "Missing argument" error?
}

// "Missing argument" error
// print(add(1, 2))

// No Error - I think I understand why this works
print(add(x: 1, y: 2))  // Outputs: 3

// How does this work?
print(wrapper(function: add))  // Outputs: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How does this work?

```
print(wrapper(function: add))  // Outputs: 3
```

### Fact 1

`wrapper` is a function which receives 1 argument with this type:

```
(Int, Int) -> Int
```

### Fact 2

The type of your `add` function is

```
(Int, Int) -> Int
```

You can confirm this with Xcode:

1. Assign your function to a constant
2. ctrl + click on the constant name

[image]

### Conclusion

Since the type of the argument of `wrapper` is the same of `add`, then this code compiles

```
wrapper(function: add)
```

### Additional question from comment

> can you explain a bit more on why the arguments are needed when its called outside and no longer needed when it's called inside a function?

Because:

1. Closures in Swift don't have external parameter names.
2. You can pass a function where a closure is required, as long the the input type and output type do match.

So when you write

```
wrapper(function: add)
```

you are passing the `add` function to `wrapper`.
This is allowed because the types do match.

Then when you write

```
func wrapper(function: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int {
    function(1, 2)  // Why does this not produce a "Missing argument" error?
}
```

In the second line you are now invoking a `closure` which does not have external parameter names.

Comment: Thank you for responding, can you explain a bit more on why the arguments are needed when its called outside and no longer needed when it's called inside a function?

Comment: @Valencia I have replied in the new paragraph on my answer.

Comment: thank you, I really don't know whose answer to accept, both of this collectively made me understand this :)

Comment: Both good answers, difficult pick, but you get points for faster response and screenshots :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain short and simple.

In Swift, you can [ignore many things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58665962/5623035) that you don't care about. (for example values, numbers, names, etc.)

In functions, there are two names (labels) for each parameter:

```
func example(externalName internalName: MyType) -> ReturnType
```

You can ignore the names you don't care about with `_` like:

```
// Don't care about the external name
func example(_ internalName: MyType) -> ReturnType

// Will be called like
example("Some Value")

// --------

// Don't care about the external name
func example(externalName _: MyType) -> ReturnType

// Will be called like
example(externalName: "Some Value")
```

The type of the `function`  parameter in the `wrapper` is `(Int, Int) -> Int` which means something that takes two integers and returns an Integer. The higher order function doesn't care about the external names of the parsing function. Because you are NOT going to use any of those names inside.

Basically you always don't care about the argument names when you are looking at the function (or closure) as a type!

Comment: Thank you for responding, I will re-read this again to fully understand what you meant and will accept it in a while

Comment: `// Don't care about the external name` Did you mean to say "internal name" the second time?

Comment: My apologies I had to choose the other answer, but in reality both of these combined is what made things clear to me

Comment: No I mean the **external name**, you can have something like `(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int` since it is a valid signature.